# How to add edgeInsets for each cell in Collection view -Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to create a **custom cell with top,left,bottom spacing for each cell**. Is there any collection view data source methids, inorder to specify the cell insets in each indexpath.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: block.blockCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BlockBaseClass

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10

    return cell
    }
```

But the layout is not working, inside the cellforitemAt indexpath.

Answer (score 1):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0) // top, left, bottom, right
}
```

Comment: how to give the insets of each cell? like each indexpaths

Comment: this will get applied to all cells by default, add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout `

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

By the help of this delegate function you can:

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionat section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 50, 15, 50)
}

This UIEdgeInsetsMake ( CGFloat top,CGFloat left,CGFloat bottom,CGFloat right);

Comment: 1st given is the function of customizing the edgeInsect